# How to do block selection in `screen`

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

In vim, there's a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to do block selection.

How can I do it in `screen`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you already know how to use <kbd>Space</kbd> to do normal selection in `screen`'s copy mode, the only new keys you need are <kbd>c</kbd> to set the left margin, and <kbd>C</kbd> to set the right margin.

This is described in the [`screen` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Specials).

Comment: And how can you past the selected text somewhere else then?

Comment: @rubo77 `Ctrl + A ]`

Answer (score -1):

Selection for copy: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>  <kbd>[</kbd>

Copy current selection (First to select start corner, second to copy selected area):
<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Cancel current selection:
<kbd>Esc</kbd>

Paste into screen:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>  <kbd>]</kbd>

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  Even according to the accepted answer's link, this is correct.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter but I imagine the reason was because this answer does not address the question of how to do *block-wise* selection, which is the reason I felt the need to post a 2nd answer in the first place.

Comment: Aha, I suppose that's what I get for not checking immediately before posting - I'm certain there is a key combination similar to what I posted (not using c and C, I've done it before) that does block selection, but mine is regular selection

Comment: Well, if you ever find it, update your answer and I'll give you an upvote myself.